# How to generate User_token using Facebook C# SDK

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to perform a search for public posts by facebook graph api.

I got the access token by executing this code:

```
        dynamic tokenInfo =
          fb.Get(
            String.Format(
              "/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&grant_type=client_credentials",
              ConsumerKey,
              ConsumerSecret));

        var appAccessToken = (string)tokenInfo.ToString();// tokenInfo.access_token;
```

And I put this access token in my url like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?access_token=111111111111111|xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx&type=post&metadata=1&callback=display&q=voyage&since=2013-07-10&limit=500000
```

But I'm getting the message bellow:

```
/**/ display({
   "error": {
      "message": "(#15) Requires session when calling from a desktop app",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 15
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to find the answer to the same question,
From what i learned,

We need to get User_token and use it as,

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?access_token={User_token}&type=post&metadata=1&callback=display&q=voyage
```

You can get an User_token at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/

Then it is indeed working.
But the question is how do we generate User_token?

Comment: Yes HTD, this is the question. And I got a little detail, my don't have any user interact, so, I need to do that without any user interface or action.

Comment: Since, facebook updated the api from 10th July,2013. You can't generate the freaking user access_token without loging-in the user.

Comment: Yes, I'm workaround since 10th July 2013. There isn't any simply way to generate this user token? God!